# How to close ONLY the instance of Excel that was opened by OLEFormat.Activate

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-word

Ok, I'm creating a Word document (based on a template) from MS Access and updating several charts by using the OLEFormat object.  Once I .Activate the object, which creates a new instance of Excel, and make my edits, I close that instance of Excel with:

```
wdChart.ChartData.Workbook.Application.Quit
```

This works fine if there are no other instances of Excel running.  But, if there is an open instance of Excel when the OLEFormat.Activate happens, it doesn't create a new instance of Excel, but opens the chart spreadsheet in the same instance of Excel that is open.  So when I execute the .Application.Quit command, it closes ALL open workbooks in that instance and prompts me to save the workbook.  At this point, I get a Word message that says:

> To insert a chart, you must first close any open dialog boxes or
>   cancel editing mode in Microsoft Excel

The my code fails with a:

> Method 'Activate' of object 'ChartData' failed

I think these errors have to do with the fact that my code is sequentially editing several charts.  When the Word dialog pops up, my code is still trying to run or something.

I think what would solve all of this is if there is a way to force the OLEFormat.Activate to open it's own instance of Excel.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check to see if there are more than 1 workbooks open. If so, then close the chart workbook, otherwise, quit the application.

```
If wdChart.ChartData.Workbook.Application.Workbooks.Count > 1 Then
    wdChart.ChartData.Workbook.Close saveChanges:=False
Else
    wdChart.ChartData.Workbook.Application.Quit
End If
```

Comment: Ah! I looked for a "Close" option, but was looking for a member of "Application" not "Workbook".  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with this and with "AddChart", for some reason in Office 2010(not 2013 or 2016) sometimes when accessing multiple charts in a row the excel windows doesn't close before another one opens. This causes the error that @MultiGuy experienced.

I my case I just added a small wait time in front of my "Activate" and "AddChart" calls and it seems to have resolved the issue:

```
Excel.Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
```

Long term I should probably write some sort of function that waits until the associated excel window has closed, but for now I think this much more brittle approach will work in most scenario's.